# EF Core 7 & ASP.NET Core MVC razor view does not use metadata attributes from partial class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I have to assume this is a bug, as I can't find any solution to this. I have EF Core 7 scaffolded partial classes in an assembly dedicated to data access.

This is the generated one:

```
namespace EF.DataAccessLayer;

public partial class ServerComponentConfiguration
{
    public int ServerComponent { get; set; }

    public string Element { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Property { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Value { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public virtual ServerComponent ServerComponentNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This is the the metadata I've added in a separate file, in the same assembly:

```
namespace EF.DataAccessLayer;

[MetadataType(typeof(ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata))]
public partial class ServerComponentConfiguration 
{
}

public class ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata 
{
    [Display(Name = "Last Update")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

I've used this code inside the controller to see during runtime that the attributes from my partial class are merged into the EF generated `ServerComponentConfiguration` class:

```
var metadataTypeAttribute = typeof(ServerComponentConfiguration).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as MetadataTypeAttribute;

if (metadataTypeAttribute != null) 
{
    var metadataClassProperties = metadataTypeAttribute.MetadataClassType.GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in metadataClassProperties) 
    {
        var displayAttributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true);
        var displayFormatAttributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), true);
    }
}
```

This is the Razor view, with this declaration at the top:

```
@using EF.DataAccessLayer;
@model IEnumerable<ServerComponentConfiguration>
```

This view does not see or use the attributes.

Edit: for completeness, I am using

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastUpdated)
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastUpdated)
```

As a work around I've created a class that duplicates the entire generated EF class, add the attributes there, populated the values with unnecessary duplication, and it works. So the only thing I can figure is that the way the attributes are implemented are to blame; but I am lost on how to correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ModelMetadataType attribute can specify the metadata class to be associated with the data model class, you can try changing the property to:

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata))]
```

Here is an example you can use as a reference:

My model:

```
public partial class ServerComponentConfiguration
{
    public int ServerComponent { get; set; }

    public string Element { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Property { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Value { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }


}

[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata))]
public partial class ServerComponentConfiguration
{
}

public partial class ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata
{
    [Display(Name = "Last Update")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{           
     ServerComponentConfiguration model = new ServerComponentConfiguration
     {
         LastUpdated = DateTime.Today
                
     };

     return View(model);
}
```

My page:

```
@using Dropdowm.Models;
@model ServerComponentConfiguration

<p>Last Updated: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastUpdated)</p>
```

This is the result of using `[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata))]`:

[image]

This is the result of using
`[MetadataType(typeof(ServerComponentConfigurationMetadata))]`:
[image]

Comment: This requires the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core package to be installed. This isn't a package you would normally want to include in a dedicated EF7 DAL project that doesn't have any MVC components in it. The DAL isn't MVC bound, it is used by other applications/services that don't use MVC.  But since this is for an MVC view, I can create a tiny justification for including it. I'll test this out today and see how it looks.